# sharepoint link not working in IE but working in Firefox

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, hyperlink

I have a problem with one of the links in a column of my XsltListViewWebpart. It's working perfectly fine in Firefox, but when I click it in IE, nothing happens.

The code for the link is:

```
<a onclick="EditLink2(this,82);return false;" href="{concat('/folder1/folder2/Page.aspx?RootFolder=',$thisNode/@FileRef.urlencode,'&amp;SourceID=',$thisNode/@ID)}"><xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef" /></a>
```

Is there a reason why IE refuses to understand this link? I'm puzzled.

edit: I just discovered it only works in IE when I right click the link and select open, or open in new tab. For some reason left click doesn't work.

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Regards,

Comment: got it. it was the default popup blocker in IE. I apologize for wasting the community's time.

Comment: glad you find the answer. Please answer to your question instead of commenting it. This will allow you to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default popup blocker in IE was creating problems. I added an exception for the website in its settings and the problem is now solved.